# sort an array of floats in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have an array of (4) floating point numbers and need to sort the array in descending order. I'm quite new to c++, and was wondering what would be the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a non-default comparator:

```
float data[SIZE];
data[0] = ...;
...

std::sort(data, data + size, std::greater<float>());
```

Comment: For the beginner, `std::sort` is defined in the `<algorithm>` header in STL. Of course if this is a homework exercise, you should probably implement your own `sort` function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

```
float my_array[4];
```

You can sort it like so:

```
#include <algorithm>

// ... in your code somewhere
float* first(&my_array[0]);
float* last(first + 4);
std::sort(first, last);
```

Note that the second parameter (`last`) is pointing to *one past* the end of your 4-element array; this is the correct way to pass the end of your array to STL algorithms. From there you can then call:

```
std::reverse(first, last);
```

To reverse the contents of the array. You can also write a custom comparator for the `sort` routine, but I'd consider that a step above beginner-level STL; it's up to you.

Comment: You missed the "in descending order" part of the question.